# Generación de datos acumulados

Tags: r

Estoy creando una Base de Datos generados al azar desde medias determinadas previamente, y luego trato de acumular.

Generación de datos

```
Ma <- NULL
Base.datos<-NULL
Rep <- 3 # Número de muestras

for (i in 1:Rep){
    Nt <- 5
    Replicas <- 10
    media.peso <- c(50,40, 45, 55, 60)
    sigma <- 3
    ntotal <- Nt * Replicas
    eps <- rnorm(ntotal, 0, sigma)
    x <- rep(1:5, rep(Replicas, Nt))
    medias <- rep(media.peso, rep(Replicas, Nt))
    X <- as.matrix(model.matrix(~ as.factor(x)-1))
    y <- as.numeric(X %*% as.matrix(media.peso) + eps)
    DATOS <- y
    SITIO <- x
    MUESTRA <- rep(i,(Replicas * Nt))
    Ma<-data.frame(DATOS,SITIO,MUESTRA)
    Base.datos<-c(Base.datos,Ma)
}
```

Quiero acumular las muestras en un data.frame  e.g.:

Base.datos

```
      DATOS SITIO MUESTRA
1  45.72379     1       1
2  49.70794     1       1
.........................
4  52.94830     1       3    
5  49.80673     1       3
```

Pero no logro encontrar la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Toto, que tal,

Ten presente que para "apilar" data frames debes usar la función `rbind` (`r` de row: filas, `bind`: concatenar), por tanto

```
Base.datos<-c(Base.datos,Ma)
```

lo cambias por

```
Base.datos <- rbind(Base.datos,Ma)
```

En general `c` es usado para concatenar elementos en un vector `c(c(1, 2), 3)`.

Por último, como recomendación, todo lo que sea fijo dentro del bucle/for, como lo es `replica`, `sigma` pon lo antes/fuera del for, esto ayudará a tener un mejor rendimiento para cuando crees una tabla más grande ;)

Comment: Estimado @jbkunst, funciona muy bien, y las recomendaciones que me das, también.   Excelente trabajo, muchas gracias